# Ошибка при запуке сервера в джанго

Tags: python-3.x, django

Выполняю этот код в командной строке python manage.py runserver и выходит ошибка:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x04210660>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\filters.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
  File "C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py", line 151
    '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
    ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки в студию

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Мне не удалось найти эту строчку в коде Django. Какая у вас версия и как вы её устанавливали?

Comment: Версия 1.11.1. Устанавливал через pip install django.

Comment: Эта ошибка [была исправлена в Django 1.11.17](https://github.com/django/django/commit/568c2f45ef531257a600c0e6ff8fe02525d7ab4e), ставьте версию 1.11.17

Comment: А если вдруг вы создаёте новый проект, а не запускаете существующий, то не скромничайте и ставьте сразу версию 2.1, не надо на старье сидеть)

Comment: А как установить нужную версию. Пишу pip install django, пишет что установлена.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade "Django>=1.11,<2.0"` — поставит последнюю доступную 1.11.x

Comment: Если вы запускаете существующий проект, то я подозреваю, что Python 3.7 для него окажется слишком новым и придётся ставить более старый питон (какой — вам виднее)

Comment: Спасибо, все без ошибок прошло.